# animate slide a div when li selected without animate()

Tags: javascript

I was trying to animate my topbar by adding a `position: absolute` `<div>` which `left` style attribute was changing depending of the selected tab.

After so much trying, I don't get the right way for not to start from the beginning if I try to go from the second to the third tab.
The main problem for this case is here:

```
element.style.left = ((to - last) * 33 * delta) + (last * 33) + '%';
```

`delta` is starting at 0 and ends at the indicated value. It should be starting at the actual position.

As well, I tried to go from the third tab to the second and I didn't get the solution.

Here bellow I paste the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oA1uIrHvXCcJ8TCWYeTs) where I've been working.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because you didn't set `last` after the animation completes. I added an `onComplete` callback in your script to handle that. Also, the step function in both directions actually use the same formula:

```js
'use strict';

var last = 0;

function elastic(progress) {
  return Math.pow(2, 10 * (progress - 1)) * Math.cos(20 * Math.PI * 1.5 / 3 * progress);
}

function linear(progress) {
  return progress;
}

function quad(progress) {
  return Math.pow(progress, 2);
}

function quint(progress) {
  return Math.pow(progress, 5);
}

function circ(progress) {
  return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(progress));
}

function back(progress) {
  return Math.pow(progress, 2) * ((1.5 + 1) * progress - 1.5);
}

function bounce(progress) {
  var a, b, result;
  
  for (a = 0, b = 1, result; 1; a += b, b /= 2) {
    if (progress >= (7 - 4 * a) / 11) {
      return -Math.pow((11 - 6 * a - 11 * progress) / 4, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2);
    }
  }
}

function makeEaseInOut(delta) {
  return function (progress) {
    if (progress < 0.5) {
      return delta(2 * progress) / 2;
    } else {
      return (2 - delta(2 * (1 - progress))) / 2;
    }
  };
}

function makeEaseOut(delta) {
  return function (progress) {
    return 1 - delta(1 - progress);
  };
}

function animate(opts) {
  
  var start = new Date();
  
  var id = setInterval(function () {
    
    var timePassed = new Date() - start;
    
    var progress = timePassed / opts.duration;
    
    if (progress > 1) {
      progress = 1;
    }
    
    var delta = opts.delta(progress);
    
    opts.step(delta);
    
    if (progress === 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
      opts.onComplete();
    }
    
  }, opts.delay);
}

function move(to) {
  var element = document.getElementById('nb-line');
  var delta = quint;
  var duration = 400;

  animate({
    delay: 10,
    duration: duration || 1000,
    delta: delta,
    step: function (delta) {
        element.style.left = (((to - last) * 33 * delta) + (last * 33)) + '%';
    },
    onComplete: function() {
      last = to;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.li-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#nb-line {
  width: 33%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="li-cont">
      <li><a onclick="move(0)">1</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="move(1)">2</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="move(2)">3</a></li>
    </div>
    <div id="nb-line"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: huh! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I find that the easiest way to animate things is to directly set the css transition-duration attribute of the element in question, say to one second, and then simply change the coordinates of the element with one line of javascript. The javascript will move the element and the transition attribute will ensure that it does so smoothly. Try adding something like this to the css (where the "#element" is whatever the id of the element is):

```
#element{
transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

and then make the javascript animation bit into one simple line that just changes the left attribute:

```
element.style.left = whateverItNeedsToBe;
```

Comment: Even though this is also a possible solution, I was trying to do that with javascript. But thanks for your response!